# How to store Highcharter maps in order to use them without an Internet connection?

Tags: r, shiny, r-highcharter

Usually, as the [hcmap()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/highcharter/versions/0.7.0/topics/hcmap) function explains, the representation of the map gets downloaded on each Shiny session, unless we change the `download_map_data` parameter.

If we set it to `FALSE`, then it tries to fetch it locally.

In order to download the maps, we have the [download_map_data()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/highcharter/versions/0.7.0/topics/download_map_data) function.

But while trying to merge it all together, I can not make it work as expected.

Example:

```
require(dplyr) 
data("USArrests", package = "datasets")
USArrests <- mutate(USArrests, "woe-name" = rownames(USArrests))
usa_map <- download_map_data(url = "countries/us/us-all", showinfo = F)

hcmap(map = usa_map, data = USArrests,
      joinBy = "woe-name", value = "UrbanPop",
      name = "Urban Population", download_map_data = F)
```

It throws an error. How is the preferred manner to load the map locally?

Comment: https://rpubs.com/jbkunst/Highcharter-Italy-Map

Comment: Thank you so much, jyjek. It is so weird that just by replacing the `hcmap()` function with the `highchart()` function it starts working. Should we report it as a bug?